# How do you get the Oauth2 AccessToken after its creation from the Owin Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, token, owin

If for some auditing reason I would be asked to store the `AccessToken` to Db after its creation, is there an *Owin API Class* that returns the `AccessToken` ?

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    //check user credentials
    ....
    context.Validated(ticket);
    //Where should I get the generated token?
    }
}
```

The only workaround I found is to create an Http filter in the `Global.Asax` that reads the output stream and get the Token from there.

Is there a more elegant way to get it directly from the *Owin Api*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure you can but you need to use Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth version 3.0 not 2.1 and then override TokenEndpointResponse in class OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider as the code below

```
public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
    {
        var accessToken = context.AccessToken;
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

Comment: on logout i need to clear the accessToken from my web API, please let me where it will stored.

Comment: Any ideas on how to change the access token? context.AccessToken = "newToken" doesn't see, to work as it doesn't have a setter.